# Entity Framework cascade delete configuration

Tags: entity-framework

here are two entities of my model with fluent entityframework configuration of it

**Player.cs**

```
public class Player
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Statistics Statistics { get; set; }

}
```

**Statistics.cs**

```
public class Statistics
    {
        public int GamePlayed { get; set; }
        public int Assists { get; set; }
        public int Goals { get; set; }
    }
```

**DbContextClass**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Player>()
            .HasOptional(x => x.Statistics)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(x => x.MapKey("StatisticsId"));
```

In the end, a foreignKey named 'StatisticsId' is create on my Player Table which is ok. I want on a player deletion, to cascadeDelete related stats. Here's my problem, adding WillCascadeDelete to my statement as

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Player>()
                .HasOptional(x => x.Statistics)
                .WithMany()
                .Map(x => x.MapKey("StatisticsId"))
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

results as deleting the player when statistics are deleted. How could I make this work the opposite way by keeping StatisticsId foreignKey on the player table ?

The main point here is that `Statistics` can 'live alone' without any `Player` related. Is it possible to set Entity Framework to auto delete related `Statistics` or this has to be done manually ?

Answer (score -1):

I assume you just need to add `WillCascadeOnDelete` to `Statistics` :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Statistics>()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

I haven't tested though.